# Developing a VSCode Extension to Add Color Blocks and Support Interactive Color Modification

Tags: vscode-extensions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfEFn.png)

I am looking to develop a Visual Studio Code (VSCode) extension that includes a feature to add a small square in front of color codes (e.g., #fff), with the square's background color matching the color in the current source code but without altering the code itself. When hovering over this color, a small window with a hover-like effect should appear, allowing me to interactively modify the color in the source code.

My current approach involves using the VSCode API within the extension, but I lack specific details on implementation. I am seeking guidance on how to retrieve the value of the currently selected color, insert a small square in the code, and create an interactive hover effect for color modification.

Are there any similar use cases or could you provide relevant documentation or tutorials on achieving this?

Thank you!